# OpenStack L3 load balancer

Tags: load-balancing, openstack, openstack-neutron

Is it possible to implement an L3 load balancer in open stack?

I want to load balance incoming traffic to a Virtual IP across multiple VMs based on source IP. Does any of the OpenStack neutron plugin have this feature?

If not, is there any other Linux based approach that I could use to implement this feature?

HA proxy and OpenStack LBaaS is not suitable for me as there are L4 load balancers and handles only TCP and UDP traffic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to do L3 load-balancing in OpenStack. OpenStack has a project for this called **Octavia** (Load-Balancer-as-a-service).

1. Install OpenStack `Octavia` using the info in:
   https://docs.openstack.org/octavia/latest/contributor/guides/dev-quick-start.html

   https://github.com/openstack/octavia
2. Add the following in `/etc/neutron/neutron_lbaas.conf`:

   ```
   service_provider = LOADBALANCERV2:Octavia:neutron_lbaas.drivers.octavia.driver.OctaviaDriver:default
   ```
3. Add the following in `/etc/neutron/neutron.conf`:

   ```
   [octavia]
   base_url=http://<IP address of OpenStack controller node>:9876
   ```
4. Add the following in `/etc/octavia/octavia.conf`:

   ```
   [neutron]
   service_name = <name of the neutron service in the keystone catalog>
   endpoint = <custom neutron endpoint if override is necessary>
   ```
5. Sample configuration file for `Octavia` is at https://github.com/openstack/octavia/blob/master/etc/octavia.conf.

Comment: To my knowledge, Octavia is TCP/HTTP based load balancer. In other words, it is an L4 or L7 load balancer. 

For my requirement, I would need an IP (L3) load balancer. Basically, I need to load balance incoming IP traffic based on source IP.

Comment: @Murli See the _"Source IP"_ section in https://docs.openstack.org/octavia/newton/specs/version0.9/active-active-distributor.html#affinity-of-flows-to-amphorae about how to do load-balancing based on source IP.